# Все значения из QuerySet

Tags: django

Доброй ночи. Делаю первые шаги в джанго. Не получается вывести в html-шаблоне все значения из этого `QuerySet`. Через обычный `for` в пайтон файле получается, но в шаблоне что-то никак.

```
QuerySet [
    {'author': 'bodia',
     'data': datetime.date(2019, 7, 6),
     'text': 'нормальный кум за свои деньги.'},
    {'author': 'Yegor',
     'data': datetime.date(2019, 7, 8),
     'text': 'Пайтон спасет мир. Пишите на пайтон.'}
]
```

views.py

```
def toshow_comments(request):

    comments = Comment.objects.values('author','data','text')
    print('comments--',comments)
    return render(request,'firstblog/currentpost.html',
                  context = {'comments': comments})
```

html

```
<div class="comments-post">

    {% for v in comments %}
         <br>{{ v.author }}
    {% endfor %}

</div>
```

Comment: Покажите как вы пытаетесь и объясните, что именно значит "не получается".

Comment: Что выводится в py-файле и что выводится в шаблоне? Больше подробностей в вопрос